# Why doesn't server receive messages from client?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to implement code for rating movies using sockets, but server and client don't execute every my request. Is this way of implementation good? In one moment it looks as all is blocked. When I try to write a movie , do- while loop never stops. It is one more problem. Codes are below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Server{
public static int test_port=12345;
private int port;
BufferedReader br;
PrintWriter toUser;
BufferedReader fromUser;
public static HashMap\<String,Double\> listOfMovies=new HashMap\<\>();
public static HashMap\<String,Integer\> counter=new HashMap\<\>();
public static void main(String\[\] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Server server=new Server(Server.test_port);
server.execute();

    }

private void execute() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try(ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(port)){
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Movies.txt")));
            
        
            for(Entry<String,Double> m: listOfMovies.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
            }
            while(true) {
                Socket client=s.accept();
                fromUser=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                toUser=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                System.out.println("Client connected!");
                toUser.println("Welcome!");
                toUser.println("Write movie that you want to rate:");
                String line;
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    String movie=line;
                    listOfMovies.put(movie,0.0);
                    counter.put(movie, 0);
                    toUser.println(line);                   
                }
                toUser.println("Pick a movie:");
                
                System.out.println(fromUser.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public Server(int port) {
this.port=port;
}
}
```

```
package movies;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
private String hostname;
private int port;
BufferedReader fromServer;
PrintWriter toServer;
ArrayList\<String\> list=new ArrayList\<String\>();
public static void main(String\[\] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Client client=new Client("localhost",Server.test_port);
client.execute();
}
private void execute() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try(Socket client=new Socket(this.hostname,this.port)){
System.out.println("Client connected to server: "+this.hostname);
fromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
toServer=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
while(true) {
String line=fromServer.readLine();
while(line!=null) {
System.out.println(line);
list.add(line);
line=fromServer.readLine(); 
}
//fromServer.close();
//toServer.close();
toServer.println("ll");
System.out.println(list.contains("Kika"));
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String movie=" ";
while(!list.contains(movie)) {
movie=sc.nextLine();
}
toServer.println(movie);
}
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public Client(String hostname,int port) {
this.hostname=hostname;
this.port=port;
}
}
```

I don't understand why this code is not good.
For example, these two lines

```
toServer.println("ll");
System.out.println(list.contains("Kika"));
```

do not anything.

Comment: How to solve that? I red all lines and I can write whatever, but after that nothing happens.

Comment: or just test if the server sent `"Pick a movie:"` as condition to exit the loop and ask for user input (not the best *protocol*, but a start) || as it is now the client still waiting for data from the server

Comment: Yes, server sent "Pick a movie:".

Comment: I meant for the client CODE to test if the server sent that - that is: on the client check if it received `"Pick a movie:"` - if so, exit the loop, ask for user input, send that back to the server (I feel like I am repeating myself... )

Comment: Sorry, mistake was in stopping loop. Loop wasn't stopping and then I stopped loop knowing how many lines client have to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application protocol design is broken. You are operating in 'line mode'. For a new connection, the server writes exactly 2 lines and then expects to receive lines.

```
 toUser.println("Welcome!");
 toUser.println("Write movie that you want to rate:");
 String line;
 while((line=br.readLine())!=null) ...
```

Meanwhile, your client code expects to receive an indefinite number of lines forever.

```
 String line=fromServer.readLine();
 while(line!=null) {
     System.out.println(line);
     list.add(line);
     line=fromServer.readLine(); 
 }
```

Only 'end of file' (connection closed) gets you out of that loop.

To fix, you have two options:

1. Have the client code 'know' (i.e., make the same assumptions) about what is going on.  In other words, expect exactly two reads before it needs to write.
2. Add some protocol to say 'your turn to write'. (Simplistic approach: line saying 'OVER' !)

Comment: The loop is finished and then it is sent "Pick a movie:" and client can write. But when I enter some text, nothing happens.

Comment: According to the server, the client **can** write. The client **does not** write.  The client code that you say "does nothing" is not actually executed.  You've been twice told (by myself and @user16320675) that the only time readLine will return null is when the connection is closed.  Thus you have application deadlock; each is waiting for the other to send something. If you have evidence that we are both wrong -- such as adding a 'print' to console immediately outside the loop -- please post it.

Comment: All right, I was wrong, but how to stop the loop. In this case I know how many lines are in given document and I can stop the loop, but generally how to solve this.

Comment: Implement some protocol to tell you. I gave one simple and silly example - have the server send 'OVER', which the client checks for. For other examples (not directly relevant here) consider http: end of headers is indicated by a blank line; end of document is indicated by either closing the connection or by preceding it with an exact byte-count.  The key point is to define some conventions that both sides will adhere to; the conventions do not need to be complicated.